# Is there a nice way to express $\psi_1$ using this orthonormal sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose that $H$ is a separable Hilbert space and $(\psi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal sequence in $H$. We define a sequence $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by
$$
\phi_n=\psi_1+\psi_{n+1}\ ;\  n=1,2,3,...
$$
Indeed, $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete linearly independent sequence in $H$ since for any $f\in H$ such that $\langle f,\phi_n\rangle=0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, we have
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \langle f,\phi_n\rangle \\
&= \langle f,\psi_1 + \psi_n\rangle \\
&= \langle f,\psi_1\rangle+\langle f,\psi_n\rangle \\
\langle f,\psi_n\rangle &= -\langle f,\psi_1\rangle
\end{align}$$
and since $\langle f,\psi_n\rangle \to 0$ we must have $\langle f,\psi_1\rangle=0$. Consequently, $\langle f,\psi_n\rangle=0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ thus $f=0$ by the completeness of $(\psi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. This shows that the linear span of $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is dense in $H$.

However, I am curious if there is a nice way to express $\psi_1$ as a series of $\phi_n$. Since each $\phi_n$ contains a part of $\psi_1$, clearly $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is **not** an orthogonal sequence and the representation of $\psi_1$ ought to be not unique. Right now, I know that there can't be the coefficients $c_n$ such that 
$$
\psi_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\phi_n
$$
My reasoning is that I will be forced to choose $c_n$ such that $\sum c_n=1$ but that would give 
$$\begin{align}
\psi_1&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\phi_n \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_{n+1} \\
&= \psi_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-1}\psi_n \\
0&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-1}\psi_n
\end{align}$$
which doesn't seems right either since it would mean that $c_1=c_2=...=0$, so such $c_n$'s don't exist.

Edit: It seems that the question is too confusing. By the phrase "nice form" I am not referring to the finite linear combination but rather anything in the spirit of expanding $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_n$. In this case we have $c_n=\langle f,\psi_n\rangle$ but this is possible because $(\psi_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is orthogonal.

Comment: (I misread at first) yes $\psi_{n+1} = \phi_n - \psi_1$ and you proved that $\psi_1$ cannot be expressed by the $\phi_n$ : it doesn't belong to $span (\phi)$. take an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be intuitively convinced

Comment: @user1952009 The point is that $\psi_1$ belong to the closure of $span\{\phi_n\}$ so I wonder if there's a nice form (not in the sense of finite linear combination, which is clearly impossible) that is similar to the case where the sequence is orthonormal.

Comment: $T[f] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f,\psi_{n+1} \rangle \phi_n$ is  a bounded linear operator, but its inverse is not, in particular $T^{-1}[\psi_1]$ doesn't exists, and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} T^{-1}[\psi_1+\epsilon f]$ neither (this has to be proved but should be true) ? I don't know what you want more with only the properties of an hilbert space

Comment: I think you are right so far: if $f$ were orthogonal to all $\phi_n$, then it would have to be orthogonal to $\psi_1$. Then since it is orthogonal to $\psi_1$ and all $\phi_n$ it follows that it is orthogonal to all $\psi_n$ hence it is zero. But I don't think you will find that there is a sequence of numbers $c_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \phi_n = \psi_1$. (If you think about it carefully, this does not contradict the fact that the closed linear span of the $\phi_n$ is all of $H$.)

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you, that was an insightful comment. I was already convinced that $T^{-1}[\psi_1]$ doesn't exist but it's nice that you pointed out explicitly.

Comment: @Ian I thought about that too, it was the reason I posted this question. As you have noticed, I know that such $(c_n)$ can't exists but what I am looking for is some similar expression (with my current knowledge, I don't know if such a thing exists or not). I understand what you said, I believe it's similar to Weierstrass Approximation Theorem where the coefficients of the polynomials keep changing as you get a better approximation.

Comment: Yes, the situation here is directly analogous to the fact that Weierstrass' theorem does not imply that all continuous functions on a compact interval are real analytic on that interval.

Comment: That said, I think this works: define $P_n$ to be the orthogonal projection onto the linear span of $\{ \phi_1,\dots,\phi_n \}$, then $\psi_1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n \psi_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi_n= \psi_1 + \psi_{n+1}$, then with

$$x_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \phi_k =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\psi_1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\psi_{k+1}}n= \psi_1 +\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\psi_{k+1}$$

you get

$$\langle x_n - \psi_1, x_n - \psi_1\rangle = 1+||x_n||^2 -2 \langle x_n ,\psi_1\rangle = ||x_n||^2-1$$

Now $$||x_n||^2=||\psi_1+\frac1n\sum_k^n\psi_{k+1}||^2=1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^2}=1+\frac1{n}$$

from orthogonality of $\psi_n$ and as such $||x_n-\psi_1|| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: In my original question $\phi_n=\psi_1+\psi_{n+1}$. By the way, your expansion of $x_n$ doesn't seem correct even if we use your definition of $\phi_n$.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I have edited to use your definition, which is after all the same with just an index shift. What expansion do you mean? I have expanded a bit to make clear how it works.

Comment: This looks much better! I was hesitating about your first response since I was not sure if you misread my question or not (your 1st definition would have $\phi_1=2\psi_1$ :)). This is not exactly what I was looking for (i.e. the orthogonal-like expansion) but nevertheless it's an interesting approach indeed. I'll accept this if no one has any more reply to my question.

Comment: You have correctly shown that an expansion of the form $\psi_1 = \sum_n c_n \phi_n =: f$ is impossible, as on the one hand $\langle \psi_1, f \rangle = \sum_n c_n =1$ must hold while on the other hand $\langle \psi_{n+1}, f\rangle = c_n = 0$ must hold for all $n$.

Comment: This is off-topic but when I type "@" in the beginning of the comment your name doesn't appear. Do you know what might be the cause?

Comment: since you are commenting on my answer I am pinged automatically. I believe the system thus suppresses the @xy